# Cannot read property 'top' of undefined jQuery/JavaScript in both Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to fix the error line of:

```
var targetTop = $('#' + page).offset().top;
```

I am trying last 3 months but still did not find a fix.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        $('.page').each(function () {
            changePage(this.id);
        });
    });
});

function changePage (page) {
    var position = $(window).scrollTop();
    var targetTop = $('#' + page).offset().top;
    var targetBottom = targetTop + $('#' + page).height();
    if (position >= targetTop && position < targetBottom && !$('#' + page).hasClass('active')) {
        console.log('id: ' + page);
        $('.page').removeClass('active');
        $('#' + page).addClass('active');
        $('iframe').attr('src', '<?=SITE_URL?>upload_files/collection/TS.pdf#page=' + page[page.length - 1]+'&zoom=45&toolbar=0&navpanes=0');
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect to stand in the var page ?

Comment: can you put a `console.log` in `changePage` to print the value of `page`

Answer (score 0):

`$('#' + page)` doesn't return any elements, which means `$('#' + page).offset()` returns `undefined`.

You can't get the `.top` property of `undefined`.

Apparently, the selector created with `'#' + page` is incorrect.

The cause is probably a undefined `id` in `changePage(this.id);`.

Comment: thank you for your quick response. but can you tell me the correct way to implement it.

Comment: Did you try to confirm if there's a undefined `this.id`?

Comment: hello stackoverflow support team please any body help me out... i am waiting your valuable response.